# Creating your own/modifying a collider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I create/modify a collider in Unity? In the plan, I want capsule collider to have wheel collider properties. I'm doing this to implement an omnidirectional wheel, the wheel of Ilona.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a mesh collider. Alternatively, you can have multiple children with their own spheres, offset from the parent, such that you can make any shape, however it will have faces inside as well which may not be what you want. Hope I could help!